# How to undo canvas antialiasing?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I draw some rectangles and then erase and redraw them to simulate movement
to the right. However canvas antialiasing makes them leave traces and I don't want to redraw the entire canvas.
[Here's what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVjkN.png)

And here is the code for that:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.width = 800;
canvas.height = 600;
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
maxFps = 15;


function loop(x) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        undoRect(x);
        drawRect(x + 30);   
        loop(x + 30);
    }, 1000/maxFps);
};


function undoRect(x) {
    context.clearRect(x, 0, 30, 30);
};


function drawRect(x) {
    context.fillStyle = 'black';
    context.fillRect(x, 0, 30, 30);
};

loop(0);
```

So far I attempted to clear a bigger rectangle than what I'm drawing but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I didn't tried your code but from fast reading only, you seem to just clear where you've drawn at last frame. Why don't you just clear the whole canvas?

Comment: @Kaiido, Sometimes canvas tutorials over-emphasize the performance benefits of clearing the minimal "dirty" portion of a canvas.

Comment: @markE, since clearing the whole canvas won't imply (as much) antialiasing calculations, I wonder if there is any performance benefits at all, and I'm not sure if we should let questioners follow such ways in here, I mean, most tutorials are written by guys who read SO Q/A ;-)

Comment: @Kaiido, Your point is what I was implying, so I'll say it explicitly: *Most of the time (and in MetaXenology's case here)  clearing & redrawing the scene is the better option*. Scenes involving thousands of drawings or scenes involving expensive filtering (eg layered image filters) might benefit from clearing only the dirty portion of the canvas. :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the code shown. `fillRect()` and `clearRect()` does not need offsetting to avoid being anti-aliased.

The problem indicates that there has been applied an offset earlier in the program, or an current issue with the browser(s).

Make sure the transform is reset before running the loop:

```
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);   // identity matrix
// start loop
```

If you still get issues then you should report this as a bug to Chromium/Mozilla, however as shown below, this is not an issue in more recent versions. You could also consider clearing bounding box +1 pixel each direction, optionally, clear whole canvas and redraw.

Here are the screen-recording results (click on image to see 100%) -

From **Firefox (v47.0b9)**:

[image: Firefox]

From **Chrome (v52 Canary)**:

[image: Chrome]

No trails (**[fiddle for test](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/fvdz77uk/)**)

Answer (score 1):

[Here's why that's happening.](http://www.mobtowers.com/html5-canvas-crisp-lines-every-time/)

Here's how to fix it:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.width = 800;
canvas.height = 600;

var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
maxFps = 15;


function loop(x) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    undoRect(x);
    drawRect(x + 30);
    loop(x + 30);
  }, 1000 / maxFps);
};


function undoRect(x) {
  context.clearRect(x, 0, 30, 30);
};


function drawRect(x) {
  context.fillStyle = 'black';
  context.fillRect(x, 0, 30, 30);
};

loop(0.5); // boop
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Offset your rectangle by `0.5px`.

Comment: @MetaXenology works for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome. It leaves traces on Firefox as well though.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no portable way to turn off anti-aliasing when drawing on canvas. This can create problems for example if you want to draw two semi-transparent polygons that share an edge as boundary pixels will not be handled correctly (there is no way to do antialiasing correctly when working on a per-primitive basis... perfectly correct antialiasing requires full-scene processing in the general case).

However if you only need to draw rectangles then you can get pixel-accurate results by using coordinates that for example are an `int + 0.5` when drawing with a pen of size 1px.

When drawing filled rects with `fillRect` coordinates don't need adjustments:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <script>
    var x = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.clearRect(x, 0, 30, 30);
      x += 10;
      ctx.fillStyle = "#F00";
      ctx.fillRect(x, 0, 30, 30);
    }, 100);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Another option is to just use multiple overlapping canvases for animation instead of drawing/erasing on a single canvas (canvas pixels are transparent by default and per-primitive antialiasing on canvas correctly updates transparency on the edges).

Comment: @Patrick Robert's answer uses the 0.5 trick but doesn't seem to work. Do you have an explanation for that?

Comment: +0.5 is needed when drawing horizontal or vertical lines with a pen of size 1px. `fillRect` doesn't need adjustment.